# Puppet sequence of execution

Tags: puppet

I want to install tomcat and opencms on a machine via puppet, but when I do it, it sometimes go for deploying the opencms and then deploy the tomcat which result in a failure. 
In another case I want to create a user and copy the public-key to his home directory, what happens sometimes, it tries to copy the public key first and then create the user..... which is also a failure. I am wondering if  I can have a sequence if execution .....
is there some way ?
One more thing, how can I know if the installed version on my server is open source or not ??
and if its not open source, will in get expire in near future leaving me with no access ??

any help :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use "require" in your opencms declaration or "before" in your tomcat.

```
package { 'tomcat':
      ensure => present,
      before => Package['opencms'],
}
```

--and/or--

```
package { 'opencms':
      ensure => present,
      require => Package['tomcat'],
}
```

Check out this doc from puppet labs on resource ordering:

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html